# Alterar a ligação do ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, formulário

Eu tenho um código e queria saber como faço para alterar o `ngModel` com botões.

**Ex:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Pessoa1.nome">
<input [(ngModel)]="Pessoa1.idade">

<button (click)="onChange1()">Pessoa1</button>
<button (click)="onChange2()">Pessoa2</button>
```

**Ts:**

```
 Pessoa1 = {
 nome:'Guilherme',
 idade:'11'}
 Pessoa2 = {
 nome: 'Gabriel',
 idade: '25'}
```

Eu tentei essa forma mas não consigo alternar entre esses 2:

```
 onChange1(){
 this.Pessoa2.nome = this.Pessoa1.nome
 this.Pessoa2.idade = this.Pessoa1.idade
 }

onChange2(){
this.Pessoa1.nome = this.Pessoa2.nome
this.Pessoa1.idade = this.Pessoa2.idade
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu usaria um array e acessaria os atributos nos inputs pelo índice, para alterar basta alterar o índice

```
<input [(ngModel)]="pessoa[index].nome">
<input [(ngModel)]="pessoa[index].idade">

<button (click)="change(0)">Pessoa1</button>
<button (click)="change(1)">Pessoa2</button>
```

```
index = 0;

pessoas = [{
    nome:'Guilherme',
    idade:'11
}, {
    nome: 'Gabriel',
    idade: '25'
}];

change(index) {
    this.index = index;
}
```

Você pode fazer um loop e colocar botões na mesma quantidade de itens no array, ou usar um terceiro campo para mudar o índice

Comment: Só uma obs, no caso aí seria **pessoas[index].nome**.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Costamilam é excelente, mas, faz a mudança do tipo dos dados de **objeto** para **array de objetos**, se quiser manter o tipo de dado original, deixo um outro exemplo ([que pode ser visto aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/troca-model?file=src/app/app.component.html)) de como pode ser feito utilizando um objeto como **`model`** e nos clicks do botão esse model é preenchido com os valores dos objetos correspondentes:

**TS:**

```
count: number = 1;

Pessoa1 = {
  nome:'Guilherme',
  idade:'11'
}
Pessoa2 = {
  nome: 'Gabriel',
  idade: '25'
} 

Pessoa = { 
  nome: this.Pessoa1.nome,
  idade: this.Pessoa1.idade
}

onChange(){
  this.count++;  // A cada clique no botão incrementa 1 em count

  if(this.count %2 == 0) {   // Se count for par preenche o model com o objeto 2
    this.Pessoa.nome = this.Pessoa2.nome;
    this.Pessoa.idade = this.Pessoa2.idade;
  }
  else {  // Senão preenche o model com o objeto 1
    this.Pessoa.nome = this.Pessoa1.nome;
    this.Pessoa.idade = this.Pessoa1.idade;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Pessoa.nome">
<input [(ngModel)]="Pessoa.idade">

<button (click)="onChange()">Pessoa</button>
```

Comment: Eu usariar um booleano se for só dois objetos, daí, em vez de incrementar o contador, faria `bool = !bool`